# Irregularity of $\{ w_1 aa w_2 \mid |w_1| \neq |w_2| \}$

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, pumping-lemma

I'm currently struggling to come up with a proof that the following language is irregular:
$$L_2 := \{w_1aaw_2 \in \Sigma^* \mid w_1, w_2\in\Sigma^* \land |w_1| \ne |w_2|\}$$
where $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$.

Now quite intuitively, the language needs to know what $|w_1|$ was in order to compare against $|w_2|$, so it has to be irregular, but I'm failing to formally prove that.

I was able to solve the previous problem from the book, which was proving that (similarly)
$$L_1 := \{w_1aaw_2 \in \Sigma^* \mid w_1, w_2\in\Sigma^* \land |w_1| = |w_2|\}$$
is irregular, which was relatively simple using the pumping lemma.

So I thought maybe there was some kind of connection between the two problems, given that $L_1\cup L_2$ is regular, but there doesn't seem to be any kind of closure property I can robustly employ in order to prove that $L_2$ is irregular.

Any ideas are welcome and many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question suggests you are looking for applicable closure properties. One approach probably is to restrict to strings of the form $b^*aab^*$.

Comment: Hm, I didn't think such a restriction could prove fruitful. I don't get the implications of it yet, but I will have a thought.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $i \ge 0$ define $w_i = b^i aa$.
For any $i,j \ge 0$ with $i \neq j$ you have that $b^i$ is a distinguishing extension for $w_i$ and $w_j$. Indeed, $w_i b^i \not\in L_2$ but $w_jb^i \in L_2$.

Then the number of equivalence classes of the set $\{ w_i \mid i \ge 0\}$ with respect to the equivalence relation "having a distinguishing extension" is not finite and, by the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem), $L_2$ is not regular.

---

Here is an alternative solution that uses closure properties and the pumping lemma following the hint of Hendrik Jan.

Suppose that $L_2$ is regular. Then so is $L' = \overline{L}_2 \cap \{b^i aa b^j\} = \{b^i aa b^i\}$, which is easily shown to be non-regular using the pumping lemma.

Indeed, suppose that $L'$ was regular, and let $p$ be its pumping length. For some $k \in \{1, \dots, p\}$, the word $b^p aa b^p \in L'$ can be written as $b^k b^{p-k} aa b^p$ such that $b^{ki} b^{p-k} aa b^p \in L'$ for every $i \ge 0$. Nevertheless, for $i=0$ we have $b^{p-k} aa b^p \not\in L'$, yielding a contradiction.

Comment: That's the first time I hear of that theorem, I will have a look at it. But since we haven't learned it yet, I guess the proof is achievable in a more, so to speak, simplistic manner. Thank you!

Comment: @D.Petrov. I added an alternative solution.

Comment: Thank you a hundredfold! That's exactly what I was looking for! Also reveals the implications of @HendrikJan's suggestion as well. Also, your proof for the irregularity of $L'$ is exactly the same as mine, which is another nice confirmation that I've got it right!

Comment: For your first line, did you mean to say that "Indeed, $w_ib^i\not\in L_2$ but $w_jb^i\in L_2$"?

Comment: @justhalf, yes. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, now it's $w_ib^i$ instead of $w_jb^i$. But anyway, you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the pumping lemma directly. Let $p$ be the pumping length, and consider the word $w = b^paab^{p+p!} \in L_2$. According to the pumping lemma, there is a decomposition $w = xyz$ such that $|xy| \leq p$, $y \neq \epsilon$, and $xy^tz \in L_2$ for all $t \geq 0$. Thus $y = b^q$ for some $q \in \{1,\ldots,p\}$. If we take $t = 1 + p!/q$ then $xy^tz = b^{p+p!}aab^{p+p!} \notin L_2$.

Comment: Now that's a clever idea, thank you!